# android dynamic button with setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android, button

I try to create dynamic buttons. When a button is clicked, the color of the button will change to red. When another one is clicked, the color of the previous button should be reset to the default color.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout linear;
        linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ly);

        for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            final Button btn = new Button(this);

            btn.setId(1000 + i);

            btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            btn.setMinimumHeight(150);
            btn.setMinimumWidth(150);
            linear.addView(btn);

            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                }

            });

        }
```

How can I get the id of the non clicked button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
ArrayList<Button> mButtonList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout linear;
    linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ly);

    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        final Button btn = new Button(this);

        btn.setId(1000 + i);
        btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        btn.setMinimumHeight(150);
        btn.setMinimumWidth(150);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                for (Button button : mButtonList) {
                    if (button.getId() == view.getId()) {
                        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    } else {
                        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        linear.addView(btn);
        mButtonList.add(btn);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add implements onClickListener to Your Activity and set this listener to you button in for loop like

```
valueB.setOnClickListener(this);
```

And Override the onClick method where you get button id

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + v.getId(), 800).show();
}
```

Once you get button id you can change text color